# How to remove nested empty objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to remove empty objects from a nested JSON. I've check a fair few answers on SA but none of them are doing what I need. any assistance is appreciated. I thought that I might be able to reduce the object which is working but I had to do this  `Object.keys(obj || {})` to stop Object.keys throwing type errors on undefined objects. I'm just wanting to remove any objects that are empty {} and return the objects with values.

Thanks in advance. Jimi

!--- sample object

```
export const stocklevels = {
  coats: {
    browncoat: ["L", "M", "S"]
  },
  neclace: {},
  earrings: {
    diamond: "Y",
    ruby: "Y"
  },
  shoes: {},
  bags: {}
};
```

!--- function

```
 let newObj = Object.keys(obj || {}).reduce((x, k) => {
     if (obj[k] != null) {
       x[k] = obj[k];
     }
     return x;
   }, {});
  return newObj;
```

Comment: An empty object is not `null`. So `obj[k] != null` is going to be `true` for all keys in `stocklevels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of checking for `null` ( `obj[k] != null` ) , check for `Object.values().length` ( or `Object.keys().length`) :

```js
const stocklevels = {
  coats: {
    browncoat: ["L", "M", "S"]
  },
  neclace: {},
  earrings: {
    diamond: "Y",
    ruby: "Y"
  },
  shoes: {},
  bags: {}
};

let newObj = Object.keys(stocklevels).reduce((acc, curr) => {  
  if(Object.keys(stocklevels[curr]).length > 0)
    acc[curr] = stocklevels[curr]
    
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(newObj);
```

Note that this won't work with nested objects like

```
const obj ={ 
  a :{
    b :{
      c :{} // won't remove this
    }
  },
  d : {
    x : 'x'
  }
}
```

Comment: Using recursion you should be able to remove an empty object at any depth.

Comment: for now I only need the upper most level.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this using a recursive function that reconstruct an object from its filtered entries:

```js
const clean = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) =>
      String(v) !== '[object Object]' ? [[k, v]] :
        (v = clean(v), Object.keys(v).length > 0 ? [[k, v]] :
          [])));


console.log(clean(sample1));
console.log(clean(sample2));
```

```html
<script>
const sample1 =
  { coats:
      { browncoat:
          ["L", "M", "S"] },
    neclace:
      {},
    earrings:
      { diamond: "Y",
        ruby: "Y" },
    shoes:
      {},
    bags:
      {} };

const sample2 =
  { a:
      { b:
          { c:
              {} }},
    d:
      { x : 'x' }};


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simpler implementation: (Not meant for nested objects)**

```js
const stocklevels = {
  coats: {
    browncoat: ["L", "M", "S"]
  },
  neclace: {},
  earrings: {
    diamond: "Y",
    ruby: "Y"
  },
  shoes: {},
  bags: {}
};

function removeEmpty(obj) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      if(Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) {
        delete obj[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(removeEmpty(stocklevels));
```

Comment: You can use a **recursive** approach to check each key if it contains any objects and remove them if empty.